# Libgdx scene2d multiple rotations around different origins

Tags: rotation, libgdx, scene2d

I have an actor that i need to rotate 2 times. Each time around a different origin. But it seems the actor just saves the origin set with setOrigin() and and the rotation set with setRotation() and calculates it when drawing. So if i simply set these values 2 times its just overwriting the old one and doesnt calculate it when drawing. Is there any way to chain multile rotations around different origins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, you will not see the result until you draw your actor, it is because the rotation doesn't make any transformation on actor's coordinates or something else. Rotation just a plain value that uses only when actor draws it's graphics or someone queries for actor  BoundingBox e.g. So all the rotation transformations happens each time someone need in it.

Back to your question... If you want to apply several transformations to your actor you should somehow accumulate them and then change actor's state only once.

As solution you may have a look at `Group#applyTransform()` method, it supplied with `Matrix4` where your can flexible configure all your transformations. Of course you will have to place your actor inside `Group` object, which is a some kind of cons, but in profit you will have a deal with a matrix transformations whose are not available for a plain `Actor`.

Hope this will helpful, good luck.

Comment: Thx for the answer. This might have been a solution, too. I made it work by transforming the whole group which was holding the actor(s). Had to work around some other stuff tho. I think a good solution might be to just insert an extra group which is just holding the actor which needs to be rotated around two different origins. Set one origin to the actor, and the other to the helper group thats holding it and set the different rotations, one to the group and one to the actor.